# React / Material-Ui: Open modal / dialog after form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a pretty straightforward problem:: I want to open a modal after form submission with the entered data. I work with the Material-Ui framework and React.

I split the problem in two components: the form called "CreateCompany" and the dialog class "AlertDialog".

The form itself works, the dialog itself works. The problem is: I can't manage to open the popup modal after the "Submit" click. My approach was to change the state of "dialog" after the submission click. Then, in the dialog component I change the open parameter of the dialog based on the given props. The problem is, I get in an endless loop then.

Any suggestions?

This would be great  :)

Here is a screenshot of the form:

[image: Preview]

Here is my Create Company class:

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import AlertDialog from './dialog.component'


export default class CreateCompany extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
    this.onChangePrice = this.onChangePrice.bind(this);
    this.onChangeUrl = this.onChangeUrl.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDialog = this.onChangeDialog.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);


    this.state = {
      name: '',
      price: '',
      url: '',
      dialog: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ 
      name: ''
    });
  }

[REMOVED ALL ONCHANGE FUNCTIONS]
    onChangeDialog() {
    this.setState({
      dialog: true
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
  
    const data = {
      name: this.state.name,
      price: this.state.price,
      url: this.state.url
    };

    this.onChangeDialog()
  
    console.log(data);
    
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Add new company</h3>

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <div>
          Name<TextField id="standard-basic" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onChangeName} />
        </div>
        <div>
          Price<TextField id="standard-basic" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.onChangePrice} />
        </div>
        <div>
          URL<TextField id="standard-basic" value={this.state.url} onChange={this.onChangeUrl} />
          </div>

          <div>
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" >
          Submit
          </Button>
          <AlertDialog text={"Text"} open={this.state.dialog} />
          </div>
        
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is my Alert Dialog:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function AlertDialog(props) {


  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(props)
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  if (props.open){
    setOpen(true)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
          {props.text}
          </DialogContentText>
          <Button>Close</Button>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```